# Code in Python-smart contract

Tags: go-ethereum, python

I like to code smart contracts using python for my project.
I done a project using Flask web framework in python. I like to implement the same project in ethereum block chain. Where can I learn the python library for the ethereum access. or is there any tutorial videos for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Right [here](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html).

Comment: Hi there. Can you confirm what you're asking for? Do you want to write smart contracts in Python, or do you want "a Python library for Ethereum access"? These are 2 different things.

Comment: Check ICO framework that is using Populus and Web3.py libraries: http://github.com/tokenmarketnet/ico

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look [on this article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-develop-ethereum-contract-using-python-flask-9758fe65976e), apparently it fit exactly your requirement.